# Getting error message: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back

Tags: event-observer, magento-1

This is my code. I am trying to create a credit memo in an observer:

```
        $OldOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(12132332);

        $invoicesAll = [];
        $invoices = $OldOrder->getInvoiceCollection();

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice){
            $invoicesAll[] = $invoice;
        }
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $OldOrder);
        foreach ($invoicesAll as $invoice) {
            try {
                $creditMemo = $service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo($invoice);
                $creditMemo->save();
//                $creditMemo->refund();
            }catch(Exception $e){
                var_dump($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
```

I didn't receive any errors in browser just on the system.log:

```
Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/.../lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4039
```

I tried to use refund or save. But I still get this. 
Any ideas why ?

Comment: Not sure but try to use  Mage::log(var_export($e->getMessage(), TRUE));  instead of  var_dump($e->getMessage()); .

Comment: You can also try this :- Add one line before $creditMemo->save  $creditMemo->load(); . I guess this will help you.

Comment: nope , It doesn't . If you have any other idea, I am glad to hear it :) thx

Comment: Have you tried both ?

Comment: Yes, I tried . :)

Comment: Is there anything in logs ?

Comment: This is in the system.log : `User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /var/www/html/myproject/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4039`